# My Google Sheets API Calls are being blocked (err 403)

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets, google-api

> "code": 403, "message": "Requests to this API sheets.googleapis.com
>   method google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues are
>   blocked.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",

Nothing in google resembles that error message. I'm getting this in both my google maps html file and runscope. I have done the following:

- Enabled/included an API key for Sheets API (the same one which I've enabled for the Maps AI, which is presently working fine).
- Made the sheet public and published it.
- Made sure I'm using the correct sheet ID.

My api call looks like this:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[sheetid]/values/Sheet1!A1:C3?key=[apikey]

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. May I respectfully suggest that you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question to provide the relevant information?

Comment: And .... nevermind? It started working, under no conditions that I hadn't played with before, so I'm going to assume that some credentials or something just needed time to kick in?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the API key, be sure to check the API's that you need. [image: See under 'API Restrictions]